# Python string is not formatted as expected when spreading over multiple lines

Tags: python, newline

I'm making an app that uses the Google Places API.

This is the code snippet where I'm building a string for `types` parameter in the URL.

```
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
    #required params
requiredparams = "location="+str(lat)+","+str(lon)+"&radius="+str(radius)+"&sensor=true&rankby=distance&types="

place_types = "bakery|bar|beauty_salon|book_store|bowling_alley|cafe|car_dealer|car_rental|car_wash|car_repair|\
    clothing_store|convenience_store|department_store|electronics_store|florist|food|furniture_store|\
    grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|home_goods_store|jewelry_store|laundry|liquor_store|\
    locksmith|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|night_club|moving_company|pet_store|pharmacy|plumber|restaurant|shoe_store|\
    shopping_mall|spa|store|taxi_stand|travel_agency"
```

When I print it (`url+requiredparams+place_types`), I'm getting gaps before words that start on a new line.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=10,13&radius=500&sensor=true&rankby=distance&types=bakery|bar|beauty_salon|book_store|bowling_alley|cafe|car_dealer|car_rental|car_wash|car_repair|       clothing_store|convenience_store|department_store|electronics_store|florist|food|furniture_store|       grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|home_goods_st
ore|jewelry_store|laundry|liquor_store| locksmith|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|night_club|moving_company|pet_store|pharmacy|plumber|restaurant|shoe_store|       shopping_mall|spa|store|taxi_stand|travel_agency
```

I don't get it. What am I doing wrong?

I tried this on the console:

```
>>> d = "word1|\
... word2|\
... word3"
>>> d
'word1|word2|word3'
```

That works fine. Why not my code snippet?

Comment: That's ugly in many ways... Instead of hardcoding the string why don't you put the single words in a list and then do `'|'.join(words)`?

Comment: @Bakuriugreat idea! Thanks. I'm new to Python. Didn't think of that; seems neat and organized too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
place_types = (
    "bakery|bar|beauty_salon|book_store|bowling_alley|cafe|car_dealer|car_rental|car_wash|car_repair|"
    "clothing_store|convenience_store|department_store|electronics_store|florist|food|furniture_store|"
    "grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|home_goods_store|jewelry_store|laundry|liquor_store|"
    "locksmith|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|night_club|moving_company|pet_store|pharmacy|plumber|restaurant|shoe_store|"
    "shopping_mall|spa|store|taxi_stand|travel_agency"
)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks! That worked like magic. Pretty simple to read to.

Comment: Yes. Although actually I'm going by @Bakuriu's suggestion, but since his is a comment, and yours is still a good answer, I'm accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

Is for the identation inside the string.

Your snippet fixed:

```
pt = "bakery|bar|beauty_salon|book_store|bowling_alley|cafe|car_dealer|car_rental|car_wash|car_repair|\
clothing_store|convenience_store|department_store|electronics_store|florist|food|furniture_store|\
grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|home_goods_store|jewelry_store|laundry|liquor_store|\
locksmith|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|night_club|moving_company|pet_store|pharmacy|plumber|restaurant|shoe_store|\
shopping_mall|spa|store|taxi_stand|travel_agency"
```

or better user multiline strings `"""`:

```
pt = """bakery|bar|beauty_salon|book_store|bowling_alley|cafe|car_dealer|car_rental|car_wash|car_repair|
clothing_store|convenience_store|department_store|electronics_store|florist|food|furniture_store|
grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|home_goods_store|jewelry_store|laundry|liquor_store|
locksmith|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|night_club|moving_company|pet_store|pharmacy|plumber|restaurant|shoe_store|
shopping_mall|spa|store|taxi_stand|travel_agency"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your string looks like `"bakery|bar|beauty_salon|book_store|bowling_alley|cafe|car_dealer|car_rental|car_wash|car_repair|\    clothing_store|convenience_store|department_store|electronics_store|florist|food|furniture_store|\` (without any line break) to Python. Don't use indention or maybe concat. your string could solve that issue.

Comment: I'm using Sublime Text2. After adding a `\` at the end of every line of `place_types`, I just press enter and indentation is done automatically. I did remove the tabs and then let the new lines start right from the beginning, but still getting spaces.

Comment: http://pastie.org/8952816 Like this I still get `\t` before words that start on new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only one newline between lines, looks like you have one extra (on my phone at least). Avoid extra white space in general after the backslash + newline.